# Render list of Element from an Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I need to render dynamically key-values pair from an object. For example:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    num: {
      cheese: 1,
      meat: 2,
      salad: 3,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const numLIst = Object.keys(this.state.num).map(key => {
      return [...Array(this.state.num[key])].map(() => {
        return <SmallComp content={key}/>
      } )
    })
```

So I want to render cheese 1 times, meat 2 times, and salad 3 times. The above code is from the instructor from the course and I have no idea what it is doing from

```
return [...Array(this.state.num[key])].map(() => {
        return <SmallComp content={key}/>
      } )
```

The code works, but is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: I feel you bro! I am going through the same course ;) but I was successful in breaking down the logic and understanding what he is doing. Unfortunately, I don't remember the particular topic and video title in which he taught this one. If you can mention that I would be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: It's lesson 129.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the Object.keys alone...

There is no eleganter way, there are just other ways...

```
  render() {
      const numList = Object.keys(this.state.num).map((name, index) => {
             return (new Array(index + )).map((_, subindex) => <SmallComp content={`${key}_${subindex}`}/>)
      });

      ....
    })
```

---

`Object.keys(this.state.num)` // Get the array ['cheese', 'meat', 'salad'];

`(new Array(index + ))` // Create an array of (index + 1) length

So you loop over an array with n elements to render...